# RegExp not working on read HTML file

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

First of all, I know how most RegExp questions go; and this is not one of those, "please write my code" questions.

My confusion lies in the fact that my `RegExp` works on regexr, and in chrome's dev tools when polling the `document.body.textContent`, but not on an HTML file after I have read it in io.js.

io.js is version 1.5.1, running on windows 8

Why would it work in both places listed, but not in io.js? Am I not taking something into consideration that io.js does to read files?

My `RegExp` should be matching "`@{each ___->___} text and line breaks @{/each}`" as it does in the link below, but instead, it returns `null`

Here is what I'm trying to use: http://regexr.com/3aldk

RegExp:

`/@\{each ([a-zA-Z0-9->.]*)\}([\s\S]*)@\{\/each}/g`

JS (Example):

```
fs.readFile('view.html', {encoding:'utf8'}, function(error, html) {
    console.log(html.match(myRegExp)); // null
});
```

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>@{title}</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>@{foo.bar}</h1>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, @{foo.baz.hoo}
        </p>
        @{each people->person}
            <div>
                <b>@{person.name}:</b> @{person.age}
            </div>
        @{/each}
    </body>
</html>
```

Am I missing something obvious, like a character, that is present on the back side, but not once served?

Comment: Works on https://regex101.com/r/xG1iD2/1 too. Weird.

Comment: If you just `console.log(html)` do you see anything unexpected?

Comment: @PeterBowers Nope, it looks exactly like the chunk of HTML that I pasted in here.

Comment: What if you get rid of the `encoding:utf8` option (I'm grasping at straws...)

Comment: works fine for me , see here a demo http://plnkr.co/edit/3K1Ut9NPQcT2RQZeVtvc?p=preview

Comment: @peterBowers this sounds like a unrelated question, but how can you share the regex from regex101.com? I could not find that option. I always try to answer regex question but I can never share my answer from there.

Comment: @apgp88, I banged my head against that just yesterday when I finally got tired of seeing other people post their regex like that. Just hit the "save" button and it gives you the link.

Comment: @PeterBowers Nah, I removed the encoding part, and I get the same result.

Comment: @PeterBowers  Thanks man, you just saved my head getting banged ! :)

Comment: Did you try copy/pasting from the console.log(html) directly into your regex101 or regexr to see if some strange char is getting introduced? How about copy/paste straight from the original html on the server? You could try `od -c` on the file on the server to see if there are any invisible or otherwise surprising characters...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue here lies on the fine line between **specification** and **implementations**.

[ECMAscript 5.1 Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.10.2.16) states that:

> A **`-`** character can be treated literally or it can denote a range. It is treated literally if it is the first or last character of ClassRanges, the beginning or end limit of a range specification, or immediately follows a range specification.

[Regular-Expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#special) notes that:

> Hyphens at other positions in character classes where they can't form a range may be interpreted as literals or as errors. Regex flavors are quite inconsistent about this.

### Conclusions:

The *safe* way of including a dash `-` minus sign in a character class is by either:

- escaping it (eg. `[a-zA-Z0-9\->.]`)
- placing it as the first char. in the class (eg. `[-.>a-zA-Z0-9]`)

  - <sub>exception: in a negated class it goes 2nd, right after `^` (eg. `[^-.>a-zA-Z0-9]`)</sub>
- placing it last in the class (eg. `[a-zA-Z0-9.>-]`)

*General coding guidelines suggest placing your ranges first and ending the character class with the hyphen, this avoids ambiguity and helps readability.*

---

Summing it up, your RegEx should become:

```
/@\{each ([a-zA-Z0-9>.-]*)\}([\s\S]*)@\{\/each}/g
```

---

*As an additional tip*:

you could also rewrite `[\s\S]` (any whitespace char. or any non-whitespace char.) into `[^]` (not nothing)

which would end you up with the following RegEx:

```
/@\{each ([a-zA-Z0-9>.-]*)\}([^]*)@\{\/each}/g
```

> JavaScript ... treats `[^]` as a negated empty character class that matches any single character. - [source](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#special)

Comment: Or the first one :) Nicely spotted!

Comment: It's false, the hyphen can be after a range or a shorthand character class without to be escaped: `[a-z-2]` is allowed like `[\w-2]`. `[^]` is an old syntax that is not supported by all javascript implementations.

Comment: It was, seemingly, a combination of the dash, and my 'any char' selection. Thanks

Comment: Do you consider `[^]` a safe bet?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: Are you sure it's an old syntax? Putting the compatibility aside (which may vary between browsers for corner cases), it's explicitly **defined** in ECMAScript 5 and ECMAScript 6.

Comment: @AlanMoore: `[^]` is indeed not very safe, since it is a corner case. However, major browsers should support this, if they comply fully to the ECMAScript specs.

Comment: Regarding `[^]`, it is supported by JS RegEx (ref. to: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.10.2.13). I am however interested about the flavours it's being *phased out* in, reply to [RegEx room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25767) instead this comment thread please.